# Android: How to set the json data from Volley into the ListView?

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I've recently started to use volley and I have some problem that I find curious. I have a set of json data that I want to set within the list view .

```
{"classification":
    [
    {"1":"\u30b8\u30e3\u30f3\u30dc\u5b9d\u304f\u3058"},   
    {"2":"\u95a2\u6771\u30fb\u4e2d\u90e8\u30fb\u6771\u5317\u81ea\u6cbb\u5b9d\u304f\u3058"},
    {"3":"\u8fd1\u757f\u5b9d\u304f\u3058"},
    {"4":"\u897f\u65e5\u672c\u5b9d\u304f\u3058"}
    ],
      "result":"OK"}
```

I want to display the values from the json data above into the listView, 
so I tried it like this .

```
     JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.toString());
                JSONArray js = jsonObject.getJSONArray("classification");
               List ll = getListFromJsonArray(js);
                lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, ll));
```

Howver,the out put is not like I expected. It displays something like this .

{1=value}

Actually, I wanted to display only the value.

value

Comment: Post `getListFromJsonArray` method code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use the sample below.

```
 try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.toString());
                        JSONArray js = jsonObject.names();
                        JSONArray val = jsonObject.toJSONArray(js);
                       List ll = getListFromJsonArray(val);
                        lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
                                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, ll));

                    }catch(Exception e){

                    }
```

///custom method

```
 // method converts JSONArray to List of Maps
    protected static List<Map<String, String>> getListFromJsonArray(JSONArray jsonArray) {
        ArrayList<Map<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
        Map<String, String> map;
        // fill the list
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            try {
                JSONObject jo = (JSONObject) jsonArray.get(i);
                // fill map
                Iterator iter = jo.keys();
                while(iter.hasNext()) {
                    String currentKey = (String) iter.next();
                    map.put(currentKey, jo.getString(currentKey));
                }
                // add map to list
                list.add(map);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("JSON", e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }


        }
        return list;
    }
```